# Java - extension reversal

Tags: java, extends, comparable, treenode, keyvaluepair

If my program is using a `Class TreeNode` that extends a `ComparableKeyValuePair`

Where:

`Root` can be a `TreeNode`
and `TreeNode` is a `ComparableKeyValuePair`
Therefor, `Root` is a `ComparableKeyValuePair`,

How can I declare something like this

```
TreeNode node;
ComparableKeyValuePair tempNode;

node = tempNode;
```

Comment: You can't because the compiler cannot be certain that `tempNode` is actually a `TreeNode`. I could create a `ComparableKeyValuePair` subtype that isn't a `TreeNode`. You'll need a cast.

Comment: You can't, unless `tempNode` happens to refer to a `TreeNode`, and then you can explicitly cast it. But this seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so please explain what you really need to do that you think requires this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tempNode` is not a `TreeNode`, then you cannot do this. If it is, you can write `node = (TreeNode)tempNode`. If the cast fails, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.